# two main in visual c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, networking, console

how can I run two main Visual Studio (Visual C ++)..
I would like to have a main that represents the server and a main that is
the client and run them running on two different consoles.
how can I do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626533/two-main-functions

Comment: What has 2 `main`s got to do especially with `Visual C++` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two functions:

```
int server_main( int argc, char* argv[] );
int client_main( int argc, char* argv[] );
```

in the actual

```
int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
```

check for a command line argument ( --server or --client ) and then depending on which one is present, delegate to server_main or client_main.

When it comes to debugging, do what they've already suggested which is run two different instances of VS.

Everybody else is right in pointing out that there can be only one "main", but I think this answers what you actually wanted to ask.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to create two separate projects within a single Visual Studio solution.  Each one can be an independent console application with its own `main` entrypoint.  However, the simplest way to do that if you are wanting to debug both projects at the same time is to open two separate instances of Visual Studio, one with the client solution and one with the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two `main` functions. Either have separate builds with `ifdef` guards or a command line argument.

Comment: I dont think this is what OP is asking for,

Answer (score 0):

You have to create two separate programs. Each program will have its separate `main()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Create a library with the shared code (assuming that's what you're after here) and create two separate binaries, one for the server and one for the client.