# Java Program Unable to receive the input and program terminated prematurely

Tags: java

I'm not sure y this coding is not receiving the input for the adjust variable and gets terminated before it runs completely

```
  public class Question {
  int id;
  String name;
  String type;
  double amt;
  public Question(int id, String name, String type, double amt) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
    this.amt = amt;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {  }
    }


   import java.util.*;
   public class Answer  {
   public static void gettype(Question[] q,String adjust)
   {
     for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
     {
        if(q[i].getType()==adjust)
        {
            System.out.println(q[i].getId());
        }
    }}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int id;
    String name,type,adjust;
    double amt;
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    Answer a=new Answer();
    System.out.println("enter 2 car inputs");
    Question[] q=new Question[2];
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        id=s.nextInt();
        s.nextLine();
        name=s.nextLine();
        type=s.nextLine();  
        amt=s.nextDouble();
        q[i]= new Question(id,name,type,amt);
    }
    adjust=s.nextLine();
    a.gettype(q,adjust);
    }
     }
```

While running the code i am able to get the inputs for the car object array.But after that i am not able to get the values for the variable adjust.
So please need help with this one.
I have tried simply to print the objects at the constructor side.
But not able to receive the 9th input which will be assigned to the var adjust

Comment: Formatting and readability are poor.

Comment: Is it oky now ?

Comment: You may want to refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626533 basically you have 2 main functions and only 1 can be entry point.. That should explain the premature termination

Answer (score 0):

I think this is better.  You should understand why mine works.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private double amt;

    Question(int id, String name, String type, double amt) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.amt = amt;
    }

    int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    double getAmt() {
        return amt;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("Question{");
        sb.append("id=").append(id);
        sb.append(", name='").append(name).append('\'');
        sb.append(", type='").append(type).append('\'');
        sb.append(", amt=").append(amt);
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }
}

class Answer {

    public static final int NUM_QUESTIONS = 2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numQuestions = (args.length > 0) ? Integer.valueOf(args[0]) : NUM_QUESTIONS;
        List<Question> questions  = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < numQuestions; ++i) {
            System.out.println(String.format("Question %d", i));
            System.out.print("id: ");
            int id = s.nextInt();
            System.out.print("name: ");
            String name = s.next();
            System.out.print("type: ");
            String type = s.next();
            System.out.print("amt: ");
            double amt = s.nextDouble();
            questions.add(new Question(id, name, type, amt));
        }
        System.out.println(questions);
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer did not tell whats wrong in the code in the question

Comment: It did fix it.  It runs beautifully.  Perhaps the OP can study it and learn something.

Comment: The coding should  return the id of the questions which belong to a particular type which we enter in the adjust.